# Hiding php extension and hide subdirectory both in one url not working in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> 1 code is not working in folder1 because i am using 2 code to hide
>   subfolder
>
> ```
> my site url is looks like this mysite.com/folder1/file
> and i want this mysite.com/file hide folder1 and .php but it is not working while using 2code any solution
> ```

```
1code to hide .php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

2code to hide sub folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!folder/).+)$ /folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: The page you requested is NOT AVAILABLE
A general error has occurred

Comment: What is difference between 2 sites?